# Nginx proxy_pass failover to multiple upstream servers

Tags: nginx, failover, proxypass

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for nginx proxy_pass failover setup.

I need to proxy certain locations to backend server URL's -

```
location /Data {
    proxy_pass https://backend1.example.com/site1-url;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}

location /Photos {
    proxy_pass https://backend1.example.com/site2-url;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}
```

It works as expected, but I need nginx to failover to another server. So the obvious thing would be to use upstream:

```
upstream servers {
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com backup;
{

location /Data {
    proxy_pass https://servers/site1-url;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}

location /Photos {
    proxy_pass https://servers/site2-url;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}
```

..., but this doesn't work. Nginx doesn't understand that the proxy_pass contains upstream.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Try to add port number to server declaration: `server backend1.example.com:443`. It defaults to 80. Also `upstream` must be outside of `server` block

Comment: What do you consider failover? Look at the details for proxy_next_upstream to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `proxy_pass https://servers` and use a rewrite to go to site1-url and site2-url:

```
location /Data {
    rewrite ^ /site1-url/$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass https://servers;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}

location /Photos {
    rewrite ^ /site2-url/$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass https://servers;
    proxy_set_header X_HOST $host;
}
```

**WARNING**: I've not tested this configuration.